# Raise PropertyChanged when selected item is changed in Combobox in Silverlight MVVM

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

How to change a property change in combobox when item that is selected in the combobox is changed. Actually what i want is when a value selected in one combobox is changed then
based on the value selected other combox is to be filled.
I have implenemted INotifyProperty interface even then when you select a different value the set block of property is not getting executed.

**Let me elaborate a bit more with a different example :-** 
There are two combobox and a textblock, both combobox contain the cities name, so when a user selects the city in the second combobox the a method should be called which will give the distance between the two cities in the textblock, and i am doing this using MVVM. 
The problem is that i am not able to invoke the set block of second combobox(from where i'll call the method which will give the distance).

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the SelectedItem to a property in the code behind or ViewModel if you're using MVVM, ensuring that the binding is two way and the property implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="TextProp" >

public Collection<ItemClass> Items
{
     get
     {
          return _items;
     }
     private set
     {
           if (value != _items)
           {
                _items = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
           }
     }
 }

 public ItemClass SelectedItem
 {
      get
      {
          return _selectedItem;
      }
      set
      {
           if (value != _selectedItem)
           {
                _selectedItem = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
           }
      }
  }
```

Comment: I am doing exactly what you have written here, i am debugging it using the VIsual studio 2010 and when i am changing the value of combobox the debugger is not goingto the set block of the selectedItem property... and hence not getting the required result.

Comment: Is the binding on SelectedItem definitely working? I.e. if you set it programmatically in the code does the UI update?

Comment: The problem with the answer above is that the order of the Bindings is wrong; first you should set the ItemsSource property then the SelectedItem property instead of the other way around! `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"/>`